# How to send email to settings.MANAGER in django recipient_list

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django, I wish to have the send_email send the email to settings.MANAGERS and to the ticket issuer as well. So trying to set those in recipient_list porduced no luck. I am using class based view.

```
# views.py

...
from django.conf import settings
...

class TicketCreate(CreateView):
    model = Ticket
    fields = ['title', 'question_detail',]
    raise_exception = False   
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ticket_list')     
    template_name = 'ticket/ticket_form.html' 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user     

        send_mail(
            subject=form.cleaned_data.get('title').strip(),
            message=form.cleaned_data.get('question_detail'),
            from_email=form.cleaned_data.get('request.user.email'),
            recipient_list=['settings.MANAGERS','request.user.email',],  
       )

       return super(TicketCreate, self).form_valid(form)  

# settings.py
...
MANAGERS = [
    ('Manager', 'email_id@somedomain.com'),
]
```

What would be the solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MANAGERS` is a tuple, and only the second element in each tuple is relevant. This will work:

```
sender = form.cleaned_data.get('request.user.email')
recipients = [a[1] for a in settings.MANAGERS]
recipients.append(sender)

send_mail(
    subject=form.cleaned_data.get('title').strip(),
    message=form.cleaned_data.get('question_detail'),
    from_email=sender,
    recipient_list=recipients,  
)
```

The [`mail_managers`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#mail-managers) function does most of this for you - the only difference being that it doesn't let you control the sender email (it uses `SERVER_EMAIL`).

Note that you should be *very careful* about sending mail on behalf of other people - it is only recommended if you control the sender's domain. Otherwise your messages have a good chance of being caught as spam, with the associated reputation risk for the sending server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks solarissmoke, Because I only let logged in users send the ticket and that all users are required to authenticate with valid email address, I assume users do NOT need to enter email addres again. So, get email from the user data and insert that into the ticket.

Therefore, I modified a bit like below and all work just cool now. Thanks again and you are right about spam stuff - all under my control.

```
sender=self.request.user.email
recipients = [a[1] for a in settings.MANAGERS]
recipients.append(sender)

send_mail(
    subject=form.cleaned_data.get('title').strip(),
    message=form.cleaned_data.get('question_detail'),
    from_email=sender,
    recipient_list=recipients,  
)
```